# What's the largest sharded mongo cluster you've set up?

Tags: mongodb

I have access to about 14k unique hosts. The largest stable sharded mongo cluster I've been able to set up has 256 shards.

At 512 shards either `addShard` fails or one of the shard hosts becomes unresponsive.

Is there any inherent limit to the number of shards mongo can handle?